# No dSYM files found on iTC - this usually happens when no recompling happened yet

Tags: fastlane, dsym

My app is already on AppStore for sale;
I can also manually download dSYM from iTC successfully;

But when I'm referring to doc:

[https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/download_dsyms/[![enter](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/download_dsyms/%5B!%5Benter) image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzLMy.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzLMy.png)

If I specify version+build:

```
download_dsyms(version: "33.0", build_number: "888", platform: "ios")
```

It'll fail with an error:

[image]

Comment: No body there that can help answer this question?